# DBRefCodec does not support decoding

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a project with Java and MongoDb. I am using OpenJDK v. 11.0.18 and MongoDB Java driver 4.8.0. The following is the maven dependency from the MongoDB driver.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I modeled the data to use DBRef according to the following code

```
public class Recipe implements Comparable<Recipe> {

    private String id;
    private DBRef author;
    // rest of the code omitted 

}
```

So, at the moment that the POJO Recipe is deserialized, the MongoDB throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` according to the following stack trace

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DBRefCodec does not support decoding
    at com.mongodb.DBRefCodec.decode(DBRefCodec.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.DBRefCodec.decode(DBRefCodec.java:33)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.LazyPropertyModelCodec.decode(LazyPropertyModelCodec.java:51)
    at org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext.decodeWithChildContext(DecoderContext.java:96)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.lambda$decodePropertyModel$2(PojoCodecImpl.java:224)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.setPropertyValue(PojoCodecImpl.java:246)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decodePropertyModel(PojoCodecImpl.java:214)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decodeProperties(PojoCodecImpl.java:203)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:112)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:116)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.decode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandResultArrayCodec.decode(CommandResultArrayCodec.java:52)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:60)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:87)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:42)
    at org.bson.internal.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:53)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:87)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:42)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ReplyMessage.<init>(ReplyMessage.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.getCommandResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:538)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:423)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:340)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:643)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:119)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$OperationCountTrackingConnection.command(DefaultServer.java:293)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.createReadCommandAndExecute(CommandOperationHelper.java:233)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$1(FindOperation.java:332)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$0(OperationHelper.java:356)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:381)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$1(OperationHelper.java:355)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:381)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:354)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$2(FindOperation.java:329)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:340)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:90)
    at com.recipe.book.api.repositories.RecipeRepositoryImpl.findAll(RecipeRepositoryImpl.java:37)
```

I see that the com.mongodb.DBRefCodec throws it when the decode() method is called. Said that I ask how to make the driver deserialize/serialize the DBRef from/to POJO?

I used the BasicDBObject to save the object that has the DBRef according to the following code and it worked. But, I need to use the POJO because of other operations.

```
public void post(Context ctx) {
        //Recipe recipe = ctx.bodyAsClass(Recipe.class);
        String jsonRequest = ctx.body();

        String username = ctx.basicAuthCredentials().getUsername();
        User author = userService.findUserByName(username);

        BasicDBObject recipe = BasicDBObject.parse(jsonRequest);

        recipe.append("author", new DBRef("user", author.getId()));

        Recipe createdRecipe = recipeService.saveOne(recipe);

        ctx.json(createdRecipe).status(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```